# Asana Authorization error on Mono.NET framework

Tags: mono, restsharp, asana

I'm trying to use the Asana restful API and I receive this error:

> {"errors":[{"message":"Not Authorized"}]}

```csharp
 public static string GetProjects()
{
    string url = "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/"; // Constants.BaseApiUrl + "projects";
    var client = new RestClient(url);
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CheckValidationResult);
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(AsanaAPIKey.GetBase64(), "");
    var req = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    RestResponse res =(RestResponse) client.Execute(req);

    return res.Content;
}

public static bool CheckValidationResult(object sp,
    X509Certificate cert,
    X509Chain req,
    System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors problem)
{
    return true;
}
```

I've tried plain httpwebrequest/Httpwebresponse and it didn't work either so I tried the restsharp library and still the same problem.

Any ideas why this error is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know .NET but I see you're creating an `HttpBasicAuthenticator` and it looks like you're passing it a username/password pair. But you are passing it a base64-encoded version of the API key, which is wrong. The [documentation on authentication](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/authentication) states that when using an HTTP library you should pass the API key as the username, unchanged. You only need to manually base64-encode if you are constructing the full header manually.

Comment: Ok, So removing the GetBase64() removes the error but I get another one. But Since your answer solved that issue I'm going to mark it as answer.

Comment: The error I get is:
DllNotFoundException: MonoPosixHelper